# unlink function in CI throws warning

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter 2. when using the unlink() php function it throws the errors. Here is my model function in CI to delete files:

```
    function delete($file)
    {
        $delete_files = $this->gallery_path_url.$file;
        if(!empty($delete_files)) {  
            unlink($delete_files);
        }
    }
```

When clicking delete links, it shows the warning:

**unlink() [function.unlink]: http does not allow unlinking**

is there any alternatives function for unlink to avoid the warning

Comment: what value `$this->gallery_path_url` this variable have ?

Comment: You should never want to "avoid the warning"; moreover, in this case, you're using a URL (`http://yoursite.com/filename.ext`), which is not allowed (thankfully)

Comment: You cannot delete anything over http, try deleting a file on your folder, rather than someone else's server. you can see, the error itself says it all!

Comment: thanks for your comments, before I was not aware of that deleting file on http is not allowed

Answer (score 8):

You are trying to delete a file using an address like `http://thing/I/want/deleted`. You can not do this. Instead use an address like `/path/to/file/on/my/computer/`

Answer (score 0):

[just check this](http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/php-file-delete.php) will provide more information

The user that Apache is running under doesn't have permission to delete the file.

Comment: That might be an issue, but in this case looks like OP's using an URL instead of a path

Answer (score 0):

Your path is wrong:

```
$delete_files = $this->gallery_path_url.$file; // you cant unlink from url
//should be like for example
$delete_files = "uploads/".$file; // or whatever folder your file is stored in
```

Comment: That isn't what relative vs. absolute paths means at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

1) Check the file exists in this particular folder
2) Check the What permission have that file, you can change the permission by `chmod()` function
3) If above two conditions satisfied try with full path, `@unlink($fullpath);`